# Shortening a for loop with if statements - C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop

This is my current code:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 13; i + 4)
{
   do something
}
for (int i = 2; i <13; i + 4)
{
   do something
}
```

And so on for each value of i.

I would like my for loop to do the following without having to write out each individual value:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
{
    if(i is 1,5,9)
    {
       do something
    }
    if(i is 2,6,10)
    {
       do something
    }
```

The do something is for example, change text box text.

Thank you.

Comment: @SonerGönül, well this code isn't working. And Code Review wants working code. So no, I'd not recommend Code Review.

Comment: What is your actual question? Yes it is possible to do what you want it to do.

Comment: Modulo operator may be what you're looking for: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx

Comment: I want to have 1 for loop that uses at maximum 4 if statements saying, if the i is divisble by 4 for example, then do this stuff, if its divisable by 2 do this stuff etc. <- Just an example.

Comment: Should be noted that changing the code will not effect the complexity, and it will actually result in more lines unless there is any duplication in the "do something" parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at what the criteria have in common; they all modulo by 4 to the same thing:

```
for(int i = 1; i != 13; ++i)
{
  switch(i % 4)
  {
    case 1:
      // first do something
      break;
    case 2:
      // second do something
      break;
    case 3:
      // third do something
      break;
    case 0:
      // fourth do something
      break;
  }
}
```

An alternative approach is to increment within the loop:

```
for(int i = 1; i != 13; ++i)
{
    // first do something
    ++i;
    // second do something
    ++i;
    // third do something
    ++i;
    // fourth do something
}
```

This approach needs more caution if you aren't guaranteed a whole number of loops (e.g. you're fine here, but if you were ending at `i < 12` you'd need to test within the loop).

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for the division remainder operator `%` in combination with the `switch` statement as follows.

```
for(int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
{
    switch( i % 4 )
    {
        case 0:
            do stuff;
            break;
        case 1:
            do stuff;
            break;
        case 2:
            do stuff;
            break;
        case 3:
            do stuff;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: And this would work for each primary value for i? i = 1 do a, i =2 do b, i = 3 do c, i = 4 do d, i = 5 do a, i = 6 do b and so on...

Comment: @TomPitts You might want to move the `case 0` to the bottom since that's the one that works for multiples of 4, but yes it will work for all values of `i`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Contains`:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
{
    if(new[]{1,5,9}.Contains(i))
    {
       // do something
    }
    if(new[]{2,6,10}.Contains(i))
    {
       // do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem I have is that my for loop is actually: i < 32. Don't want to write each one out.

Comment: If taking this approach generally, I'd suggest moving the array creation to outside of the loop.

Comment: @TomPitts: since you haven't described your logic in your question i have provided a general approach. If the logic is like [Codor's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33917610/284240)  you should use that approach. Also, Jon Hanna is right, you should declare the arrays before the loop. I just wanted to show the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way without making it longer...

```
for(int i = 1; i != 13; ++i)
{
    if ((i - 1) % 4 == 0)
    {
         //i is 1, 5, 9, etc.
    }
    else if ((i - 2) % 4 == 0)
    {
         //i is 2, 6, 10
    }
}
```

Comment: And i can do that for if((i-3) % 4 == 0) so that i =3 will do something different to i =1 and i =2?

Comment: @TomPitts if you need to handle all four remainder cases then you might as well just do `if(i % 4 == 1)`, `if(i % 4 == 2)`, `if(i % 4 == 3)`, and `if(i % 4 == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
int[] valuesForTheFirstIf = new int[] { 1, 5, 9 };
int[] valuesForTheSecondtIf = new int[] { 2, 6, 10 };

for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
    if (valuesForTheFirstIf.Contains(i))
    {
        // do something
    }
    if (valuesForTheSecondtIf.Contains(i))
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```